# What is the equivalent terminal command of Update Manager?

Tags: upgrade, command-line, apt, updates, update-manager

I have always been running the following command to update via terminal my machines:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

But the other day, right after having finished installing some updates, the Update Manager popped up asking me to install some updates. I was puzzled as I have always thought the two were equivalent. I tried running the terminal command again: no updates. Then tried pressing the "Check" button on Update Manager: again some updates were available.

My conclusion is that the command above is not equivalent to the Update Manager, as I have always thought. So, what is the true equivalent terminal command of Update Manager?

Comment: Maybe dist-upgrade

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apt-get` will NOT consider "suggested" packages as updates, while Update Manager does. It Update Manager also includes packages which `apt-get` would only install/upgrade with `dist-upgrade`. Additionally, I believe Update Manager maintains its own package cache which is only automatically updated daily and thus may not always be synchronized with the APT package cache.

To really check if you're missing out on updates, check the version of *non-recommended* updates Update-Manager wants you to install, and then do a `dpkg --list | grep -i packagename` to find out which version of the package is really installed on your system.

Answer (score 10):

You can use this command:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

man page says:

**dist-upgrade**

> dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of less important ones if necessary. So, dist-upgrade command may remove some packages. The /etc/apt/sources.list file contains a list of locations from which to retrieve desired package files. See also apt_preferences(5) for a mechanism for overriding the general settings for individual packages.

Comment: But, i successfully updated Linux Kernal Image with `dist-upgrade`, which can not be updated with `upgrade`

Comment: that's true, I forgot about that since I usually compile my own kernels :)

Comment: -1, -y should never be used. It has the potential to break poorly made packages that require dealing with system-wide configs.

Comment: Thats true.. But nornally it will skip the prompt `Do you want to continue [Y/n]?`

Comment: I edited and removed `-y` :)

Comment: Won't `dist-upgrade` upgrade the system to latest nightly build available (alpha or beta)?

Comment: No, it will not.