# Why do I have updates available when I just ran 'apt-get update' and 'apt-get upgrade'?

Tags: updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the equivalent terminal command of Update Manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141119/what-is-the-equivalent-terminal-command-of-update-manager)

I logged in this morning and had a notification of 25 available updates. I ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`, and now just having finished the upgrade, I immediately get a notification of additional 8 available updates. I guess there's a difference in where `apt-get update` and the notifications utility get their information from?

Please help me sort this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some updates require more than a simple `apt-get upgrade` to install, and so you may not have gotten them installed, as they were held back. You can install them by running `apt-get dist-upgrade` instead.